# Getting script in .js file to load in HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html

I wrote a simple copyright script in javascript that I have tested to work correctly:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="footer"></p>
<script type = "text/javascript">

var initialYear = 2016;
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var yearYext = "null "

if (initialYear == currentYear)
{
 yearText = " " + initialYear + " ";
}

if (initialYear != currentYear)
{
 yearText = " " + initialYear + " - " + currentYear;
}

var copyright = {
    name : "Elliander Eldridge",
    symbol  : '\u00A9',
    year       : yearText,
};

document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML =
 "Copyright " + copyright.symbol + " " + copyright.year + " " + copyright.name 
 + ". All rights reserved.";

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

(as you can see from the run button)

So I moved the script portion into js/site.js (within the directory tree of the website files) and wanted to load this within the footer of all pages.

The problem is that using neither this:

```
<script src="../js/site.js"></script>
```

nor this:

```
<script src="../js/site.js">   
<p id="footer"></p>
</script>
```

Does anything at all, and I can't seem to find a way to get this to load at all. I also tried putting that in other parts of the page without success. I even tried putting that in the css file that every page is supposed to load.

As a side note, I'd like to be able to load more than one script from this file, similar to how I might use multiple css classes within one css file, but not sure how to go about doing this here.

P.S. - Please don't advise me on alternate ways of writing this in javascript. I just need help getting to load what I have already written.

Comment: Try putting the script tag `<script src="../js/site.js"></script>` at the end of the page, after DOM is loaded. I think the issue is the js runs but since the DOM is not loaded it cant find `footer`

Comment: If the `js` directory is the same directory as the html page you're calling it from, you don't need the `../` at the beginning.

Comment: hmm. That didn't help, and yeah, for the index page I tried it as <script src="js/site.js"></script> 

The index is top level. No HTML page is in the js folder. All other HTML pages are in the HTML folder.

Comment: Of course, the script itself does not put anything onto the screen. It's the <p id="footer"></p> that is supposed to do that. So if the .js is loaded on the bottom of the page wouldn't that prevent that line from working? In which case the output would be blank?

Comment: I dont get it. In order for the js to find the elementbyID, the element has to exist. So you call the js after page has loaded and yes it will work fine. Also pt your js code in this block : `$(document).ready(function() {
});`

Comment: @TheUknown he's not using jQuery, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: @Niek I know. I've mentioned the alternative in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your js code is called at the beginning, even before the HTML content is loaded and it tries to find `footer`, which obviously doesnt exist on the page yet.

All you need to do is call the js, once the DOM is ready i.e. the HTML is loaded

```
<p id="footer"></p>
...
... 
// and at the end of the page
<script src="../js/site.js"> </script>
```

Another tip that may help. Put your js code around this :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
//put your code here
});
```

Oh and also, this is incorrect

```
<script src="../js/site.js">   
<p id="footer"></p>
</script>
```

EDIT:

Since you dont want to use jquery, do this :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // put your code here
}, false);
```

This makes sure that the javascript code runs only after the DOM is loaded

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. When you say "at the end" do you mean after the </HTML> or after the </footer> or before </body> ? Because I tried all 3. I'm not sure what that document ready function is supposed to do, can you explain that and why it helps?

Comment: It should go right before the `</body>` tag.

`$(document).ready(function(){ codeGoesHere; });` is a `jQuery` function that runs once the DOM has finished loading, this is, all your html elements are ready to be modified. In order to use it you need to have jquery imported, you can paste this before your '</body>` tag: (and before your script tag too): `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" ></script>`

Comment: oh, yeah, I can't use j query for this. I'm half writing my own website, but half doing this for a college assignment, and I spent so much time testing to make sure the scripts themselves work I didn't consider having an issue getting them to load. This is supposed to be able to work regardless. It's following every textbook example I could find, just not working.

Comment: @Elliander Check my EDIT. Since you dont want to use jquery